# Limiting datetime_select to a certain start time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, datetime-select

Is there a way to limit datetime_select in rails so that it only shows certain hours, e.g. so that the only options are 5pm-10pm? currently only have this:`

```
<%= f.label :time %><br>
<%= f.datetime_select :time,  :minute_step => 30 %>`
```

Answer (score 6):

This will give you an hour range between 5pm - 10pm

```
<%= f.datetime_select :time,  minute_step: 30, start_hour: 17, end_hour: 22 %>`
```

Comment: That's cool... I thought `start_hour` and `end_hour` were only available for `select_time` and `select_hour`